# Why would an equation switch signs when something becomes independent of time? (Traffic Flow)

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-derivative

EDIT: I'm too tired for math and the answer to my question is explained in a comment below. Should this post be removed? Not sure if it adds much to the community given that it was all just me misreading something, but then I don't know how this website works too well anyways.

It's my first time here, so if I make mistakes or this isn't an appropriate question I trust a mod will edit/remove this.

That said, I'm looking at the development for the conservation equation in traffic modelling/traffic flow. What I'm referencing is available [here](http://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/childres/traffic2.pdf) as a PDF from nyu.edu.

We have the equation

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int^B_A \rho (x,t) dx = -q(B,t) + q(A,t)$$

A quote from the link I provided states: "We can see from our conservation law (8) [8 is the equation I posted here] that $q(B,t) - q(A,t)$ whenever $\rho$ becomes independent of time."

It continues to show the equation:

$$ \int^B_A \frac{\partial \rho }{\partial t} dx = q(B,t) - q(A,t)$$

Making it such that they can use the fundamental theorem of calculus to form another partial with the flow (q). My question is, why do they switch the signs on the flow? At first flow at B ($q(B,t)$) was negative, and the other was positive, but then they switched making this possible. I don't understand that line where they said that because density became independent of time they could switch the flows.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I think you might have misread something. Equation (10) involves $\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}$, not $\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}$

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe it was such a simple mistake. They take the $-q(B,t) + q(A,t)$ and simply subtract it from both sides, hence the switch in signs. In that case, the equals sign in the second equation of my OP should just be an addition sign, and it's all equal to zero. Thanks, @Tunococ! I think I need to get some sleep...